# after fork(), parent process can still change variable value?

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main()
    {
            int i=1;
            pid_t j=fork();
            i=4;
            if(j==0)
            {
                    printf("%d\n",i);
            }
            i=5;    // will this line runs in both parent and child?

    }
```

~

I think after fork()
in the child process, i is `1` no matter how the parent process change it
but the result is  4
why not 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the value of `i` in the parent *and* in the child. All the code after `fork()` runs in both processes.

```
pid_t j=fork();
i=4;              // <- this runs in both parent and child
if(j==0) {
   ...            // <- this runs only in child because of the if
}
i=5;              // <- this runs in both parent and child
```

The execution in the child starts at the line after fork, and then runs normally. There is nothing special in the execution of the child at all from being a "child" - normal code flow happens just as in the parent.

If you want to clearly separate what happens in the child and what goes on in the parent, make it explicit in your code:

```
pid_t j = fork();
if (j < 0) {
  // fork failed, no child created at all
  // handle error
} else if (j == 0) {
  /* In child process */
  ...
} else {
  /* In parent process */
  ...
}
```

Comment: how about the line `i=5`

Comment: Same thing. The only "magic" in fork is that it creates two processes, and the second "starts" right after the fork call. Apart from that (and the fact that `j` has a different value in the parent and the child), the code runs in both processes following all the normal rules.

Comment: so if I hope child process doesn't run `i=5`, I should use an `exit()` inside the if(j==0){} block?

Comment: Yes, you could exit inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

The code below `fork` runs in both `parent` and `child`..

Comment: @misteryes Yes.  The child process is a clone of the parent.  So it will execute that line.